# How to fixing bad access error in callback using NSMethodSignature?

Tags: objective-c, callback, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a custom modal layer. the idea is a user see's a city, clicks on said city and accepts or rejects the location.

I use `NSMethodSignature` to handle the callback so I know whether the user clicked `Tick` (Accept) or `Cross` (Reject) buttons in the modal layer.

However, for some reason the app crashes once it invokes the callback and gives me a bad access error when it returns from the modal.

```
0x000d584e  <+0174>  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x000d5852  <+0178>  call   0xd6006 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x000d5857  <+0183>  mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax  Thread 1: Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

I do not understand why this is happening as the city object is defined in the class.

For example, my .h file has:

```
@interface MapMenuLayer : CCLayer
{
    CCArray *listOfCities;
    City *city;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCArray *listOfCities;
@property (nonatomic, retain) City *city;
```

And my .m file has:

```
@synthesize listOfCities, city;
```

Later on I define the display each city on the page as clickable `CCMenu` items.  When the user clicks on a city it calls:

```
-(void) onMenuItem:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"sender = %d", [sender tag]);

    self.city = [self.listOfCities objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];    
    NSString *cityName = self.city.name;
    NSLog(@"cityName = %@", cityName);

    // Launch the modal layer
    CityModalLayer *cityModalLayer = [[[CityModalLayer alloc] initWithCity:self.city target:self selector:@selector(onDialogButton:)] autorelease];
    [cityModalLayer show:self];

}

// This is called when the modal is closed or actioned upon
- (void) onDialogButton:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"onDialogButton:buttonIndex: %d", buttonIndex);

    NSString *cityName = self.city.name;
    NSLog(@"You selected: cityName = %@", cityName);

}
```

The bad access error occurs when the application flow returns from the modal layer and launches the `onDialogButton` method is actioned.

It outputs the log fine, but it crashes when it hits the city object.  I have no idea why this is happening, it should not be null or causing any formal error.

Okay, so the modal layer is a bit complex, but I cut it down for the purposes of this question:

```
-(id) initWithCity:(City *)cityObj target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector
{
    if((self=[super init])) 
    {
        [self initWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 255)];
        [self setOpacity:80];
        [self setIsTouchEnabled:YES];

        self.city = cityObj;

        // Setup the signature class
    NSMethodSignature *sig = [[target class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    callback = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
    [callback setTarget:target];
    [callback setSelector:selector];
    [callback retain];

        // -----

        // MENU

// The frames are not in this code, but they do exist

        // Add modal menu
        // Modal Menu (Tick/Cross)
        CCMenu *modalMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:nil];    

        CCSprite *closeButtonOff = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"closeButton_Off.png"];
        CCSprite *closeButtonOn = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"closeButton_On.png"];
        CCSprite *tickButtonOff = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"tickButton_Off.png"];
        CCSprite *tickButtonOn  = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"tickButton_On.png"];

        // Tick button
        CCMenuItemSprite *tickBtnItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:tickButtonOff selectedSprite:tickButtonOn target:self selector:@selector(onButtonPressed:)];
        [tickBtnItem setTag:1];
        [tickBtnItem setPosition:CGPointMake(130, -95)];
        [tickBtnItem setIsEnabled:YES];

        // Close button
        CCMenuItemSprite *closeBtnItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:closeButtonOff selectedSprite:closeButtonOn target:self selector:@selector(onButtonPressed:)];
        [closeBtnItem setTag:0];
        [closeBtnItem setPosition:CGPointMake(-130, -95)];
        [closeBtnItem setIsEnabled:YES];

        // Add stuff to modal
        [modalMenu addChild:closeBtnItem];
        [modalMenu addChild:tickBtnItem]; 

        // Add menu to the modalFrame
        [modalFrame addChild:modalMenu z:2];

        // --

        // Add modalFrame to modalLayer
        [self addChild:modalFrame];    



    } // end if
    return self;

}

// This invokes the action
-(void) onButtonPressed:(id) sender
{
    NSInteger buttonIndex = [sender tag];

    NSLog(@"onButtonPressed: %d", buttonIndex);

    [callback setArgument:&buttonIndex atIndex:1];
    [callback invoke];
    [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}


-(void) dealloc
{
    [callback release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I have tracked the issue down to when the callback is invoked, however I do not understand why it is crashing, or giving me the error.   It should still have the city object in memory?

What could be causing this?

Comment: Hi. I think the problem is in the autorelease in    `CityModalLayer *cityModalLayer = [[[CityModalLayer alloc] initWithCity:self.city target:self selector:@selector(onDialogButton:)] autorelease];`  If I remove it, it seems fine. I am double checking for memory issues though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it now.  It was the autorelease.   Which I have removed

In order to prevent clicks under the modal, or someone pressing on a button lots of times really quickly I put a `CoverLayer` inside my ModalLayer.m file

```
// class that implements a black colored layer that will cover the whole screen 
// and eats all touches except within the dialog box child
@interface CoverLayer : CCLayerColor {
}

@end
@implementation CoverLayer
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {        
        [self initWithColor:ccc4(0,0,0,0) 
                      width:[CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width 
                     height:[CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.height];
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];
    CCNode *dialogBox = [self getChildByTag: kDialogTag];

    // eat all touches outside of dialog box
    return !CGRectContainsPoint(dialogBox.boundingBox, touchLocation);
}

- (void) registerWithTouchDispatcher {
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:INT_MIN+1 swallowsTouches:YES];
}

@end
```

Then I can init this using my `ModalLayer` implementation and then dismiss the modal with a small animation, ie,

```
-(void) onButtonPressed:(id) sender
{
    NSInteger buttonIndex = [sender tag];
    [callback setArgument:&buttonIndex atIndex:2];
    [callback invoke];

    id fadeOut    = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.2f opacity:0];
    id remove = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeFromParentAndCleanup:) data:(void*)NO];        


    [self.coverLayer runAction:
     [CCSequence actions:
      fadeOut, remove,
      nil]];
}
```

Anyway, I believe I resolved the problem as it seemed to relate to autorelease

Comment: I have since discovered the coverlayer does not really lock the underneath. You can click icons/buttons twice or more in succession and it will spawn multiple modals.  However, I have found a system which locks the child items that seems to work.